# splitting 1 row into multiple rows in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have 1 row with hundreds of columns in an array in octave/matlab

```
example of a row:  
540 6.28319 0 538.3 6.26573 0
```

I would like it to look like this.  Every 3rd column move data to next row.

```
540 6.28319 0 
538.3 6.26573 0
```

I did try:

```
tmp = [540 6.28319 0 538.3 6.26573 0];
a = reshape(tmp, [], 3); but that gives me 
540 0 6.26573
6.28319 538.3 0
```

I'm trying to get

```
540 6.28319 0 
538.3 6.26573 0
```

How can I go about doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tmp = [540 6.28319 0 538.3 6.26573 0]
a = reshape(tmp, 3, [])'
```

gives:

```
a =

  540.0000    6.2832         0
  538.3000    6.2657         0
```